# How to find a substring using two indexes/positions in Python

Tags: python

I want to find **sub-string** using **indexes**, like:

```
"I am a boy!"
```

and if I have positions 3 and 5, then the sub-string will be `"am"`.

Is there a command or way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use slicing. As indexes are 0 based in python so you've to use 2 and 4.

```
>>> strs = "I am a boy!"
>>> strs[2:4]            
'am'
```

If you're new to slicing : [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3):

Subtract `1` from indices for `0` indexed

```
>>> text = "I am a boy!"
>>> text[2:4]
'am'
```

Comment: I think SO delivers question to you first than anyone else!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing, like follows. You'll have to subtract 1 from your index, since indexing starts from 0 i.e the first character is at index 0.

```
>>> string = "I am a boy!"
>>> startPosition = 3
>>> endPosition = 5
>>> string[startPosition-1:endPosition-1]
'am'
```